# How to set up a query to select from multiple tables and bridge tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to select one character from one space and look at their inventory and the items' condition and attributes.

**characters**

| id | name | confirmed_bad_ass |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john | 0 |
| 2 | punk | 0 |
| 3 | kyle | 1 |
| 4 | vukovich | 0 |
| 5 | traxler | 0 |
| 6 | silberman | 0 |
| 7 | punk | 0 |
| 8 | sarah | 1 |
| 9 | punk | 0 |
| 10 | terminator | 1 |

**spaceAssociations**

| space_id | character_id |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 7 |
| 3 | 9 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 8 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 2 | 10 |

**spaces**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | good_guys |
| 2 | bad_guys |
| 3 | punk_guys |

**itemAssociations**

| items_id | itemAttributes_id |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 4 | 5 |

**itemAttributes**

| id | category |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | cold |
| 2 | hard |
| 3 | fast |
| 4 | slow |
| 5 | sharp |

**itemsCharacterAssociations**

| character_id | item_id |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 10 | 2 |
| 10 | 3 |

**items**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | pipe |
| 2 | car |
| 3 | gun |
| 4 | keys |

**conditions**

| id | condition |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3.5 |
| 2 | 3.0 |
| 3 | 4.0 |
| 4 | 4.3 |

I've only managed to get the members of the first team with

```
SELECT s.id, c.id, c.name, i.name, a.category
FROM characters AS c, items AS i, itemAttributes AS a, spaces AS s
INNER JOIN spaceAssociations AS sa 
    ON sa.space_id = 1
AND sa.character_id = c.id
INNER JOIN itemCharacterAssociations AS ica ON ica.character_id = 3
AND ica.item_id = i.id
INNER JOIN itemAssociations AS ia ON ia.items_id = 2
AND ia.itemAttributes_id = a.id
;
```

But don't know about the continuation.
This gives me when `s.id = 1, c.id = 3, i.id = 1`

**ACTUAL**

| id | id | name | name | category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | john | pipe | hard |
| 1 | 1 | john | pipe | fast |
| 1 | 3 | kyle | pipe | hard |
| 1 | 3 | kyle | pipe | fast |
| 1 | 8 | sarah | pipe | hard |
| 1 | 8 | sarah | pipe | fast |
| 2 | 1 | john | pipe | hard |
| 2 | 1 | john | pipe | fast |
| 2 | 3 | kyle | pipe | hard |
| 2 | 3 | kyle | pipe | fast |
| 2 | 8 | sarah | pipe | hard |
| 2 | 8 | sarah | pipe | fast |
| 3 | 1 | john | pipe | hard |
| 3 | 1 | john | pipe | fast |
| 3 | 3 | kyle | pipe | hard |
| 3 | 3 | kyle | pipe | fast |
| 3 | 8 | sarah | pipe | hard |
| 3 | 8 | sarah | pipe | fast |

**EXPECTED**

| id | id | name | name | category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | kyle | pipe | hard, fast |

I am expecting to only get the name and inventory from **one** character in chosen space, I also expect to get one row per item with the attributes in one cell

Comment: You should edit your question and show the results you want.  Perhaps small examples (or a SQL/DB fiddle) would help as well.

Comment: Added expected and actual. I don't know how to make that fiddle you mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are not joining properly the tables.
You are using join syntax with `,` instead of explicit  `JOIN` clauses followed by `ON` clauses with their respective conditions.
Also, for the sample data you posted and the requirement, you don't need a `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT s.id space_id, 
       c.id character_id, 
       c.name character_name, 
       i.name item_name, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(a.category) category 
FROM characters c 
INNER JOIN spaceAssociations sa ON sa.character_id = c.id  
INNER JOIN spaces s ON sa.space_id = s.id 
INNER JOIN itemCharacterAssociations ica ON ica.character_id = c.id
INNER JOIN items i ON i.id = ica.item_id
INNER JOIN itemAssociations ia ON ia.items_id = i.id
INNER JOIN itemAttributes a ON ia.itemAttributes_id = a.id
WHERE c.id = 3 AND s.id = 1 AND i.id = 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=3ddc108f521f4dc6b79582d8074bd7da).
Results:

| space_id | character_id | character_name | item_name | category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | kyle | pipe | cold,hard |

Comment: I realize I've writen my wonderings badly, maybe my edit is better and clearer

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the following will do what you want (except that it gets cold,hard rather than hard, fast) :-

```
SELECT s.id AS space_id, 
    c.id AS character_id, 
    c.name As character_name, 
    i.name AS item_name, 
    group_concat(a.category) AS category 
FROM characters AS c 
    JOIN spaceAssociations AS sa ON sa.character_id = c.id  
    JOIN spaces AS s ON sa.space_id = s.id 
    JOIN itemCharacterAssociations as ica ON ica.character_id = c.id
    JOIN items AS i ON i.id = ica.item_id
    JOIN itemAssociations AS ia ON ia.items_id = i.id
    JOIN itemAttributes AS a ON ia.itemAttributes_id = a.id
WHERE c.id = 3 /* character selection */
GROUP BY c.id; /* as the above gets 2 categorys GROUP by character thus group_concat function gets both categories together */
```

This results in :-

[image]

- I took the liberty of using specific column names.

I think your main issue was trying to use joins on values I guess to limit the results.

If you changed your SQL to :-

```
SELECT s.id, c.id, c.name, i.name,  group_concat(a.category,',')
FROM characters AS c, items AS i, itemAttributes AS a, spaces AS s
INNER JOIN spaceAssociations AS sa ON sa.space_id = 1 AND sa.character_id = c.id
INNER JOIN itemCharacterAssociations AS ica ON ica.character_id = 3 AND ica.item_id = i.id
INNER JOIN itemAssociations AS ia ON ia.items_id = 2 AND ia.itemAttributes_id = a.id
WHERE c.id = 3
GROUP BY c.id 
;
```

The result is close but category is repeated too frequently as per :-

[image]

> I don't know how to make that fiddle you mentioned. here's the above plus code used to build and populate the tables (perhaps the cold/hard as opposed to fast/hard is because of typos on my behalf)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/9eecb7/8098

Comment: I realize I've writen my wonderings badly, maybe my edit is better and clearer